# How to search freebase data dump

Tags: python, rdf, freebase

I downloaded the freebase data dump and I want to use it to get information about a query just like how I do it using the web API. How exactly do I do it? I tried using a simple zgrep but the result was a mess and takes too much time. Any graceful way to do it (preferably something that plays nicely with python)?

Comment: please elaborate what exactly do you want to achieve, how does the data look like and what did you try so far.

Comment: I want to query the data dump like how I query the web search API. Say I want to search about Barack Obama, I want to to give me who he is, his birth date, etc. I tried zgrep obama on the dump, but the result was a bit of a mess, nothing structured.

Comment: here's an example: http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Python

Comment: That queries the actual freebase website right? I downloaded the RDF data dump to my computer and want to query that dump.

Comment: I have the same question. Did you get a solution?

Answer (score 1):

The Freebase dump is in RDF format.  The easiest way to query it is to dump it (or a subset of it) into an RDF store.  It'll be quicker to query, but you'll need to pay the database load time up front first.